# Kubenetes readinessProbe failed in AWS EKS and ALB ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

The EKS and ALB ingress are used on our server side. Under AWS EKS, the liveness and readiness probe of the container are defined below

```
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 45
            periodSeconds: 15
```

The ALB ingress yaml

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alb-ingress
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=false
```

Recently, the pod encountered the OOM killed and was restarted successfully. We suppose that the pod could receive the network traffic after readiness status, namely 40 seconds later (initDelay 30 seconds + 10 seconds probe), however, the pod received the network traffic immediately after restarting successfully without `initDelay` 30 seconds.

---

As we know, the network traffic is forwarded to the pod by the ALB target group. We check the health check setting of the target group of ALB

```
Port: Traffic port
Healthy threshold: 2 consecutive health check successes
Unhealthy threshold: 2 consecutive health check failures
Timeout: 5 seconds
Interval: 15 seconds
```

We notice that the interval of health check in the ALB target group is 15 seconds, it seems the same value of `periodSeconds` of `livenessProbe`. If the pod encounters the OOM killed and restarts itself successfully within 15 seconds interval, the target group failed to check the failure of this pod so that the network traffic could be forwarded to this pod by the target group.

One possible solution could be to reduce the intervale of the health check of the target group, but it seems this issue could NOT be solved entirely.

Here are my questions:

- The `readinessProbe` failed in AWS EKS and ALB ingress, how to configure it correctly?
- What is the best practice to config the health check interval of the ALB target group to match the `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` of the container?

Answer (score 0):

One option is that we could enable `Pod readiness gates` on the AWS Load Balancer controller to indicate that pod is registered to the ALB and healthy to receive traffic. The controller automatically injects the necessary readiness gate configuration to the pod spec via mutating webhook during pod creation.

The pod readiness gate is needed under certain circumstances to achieve zero downtime rolling deployments in the following cases:

- Low number of replicas in a deployment
- Start a rolling update of the deployment
- Rollout of new pods takes less time than it takes the AWS Load Balancer controller to register the new pods and for their health state to turn `Healthy` in the target group
- At some point during this rolling update, the target group might only have registered targets that are in `Initial` or `Draining` state; this results in a service outage

---

`Pod readiness gate` support is enabled by default on the AWS load balancer controller. You need to apply the readiness gate inject label to each namespace that you would like to use this feature.

```
$ kubectl label namespace readiness elbv2.k8s.aws/pod-readiness-gate-inject=enabled
```

---

**Note**: this only works with `target-type: ip`, since when using `target-type: instance`, it's the node used as backend, the ALB itself is unaware of pod/podReadiness in such case.

---

Source: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/pod_readiness_gate/